# JavaScript - Take out Object from Array and place its contents at the same height

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to solve the following problem in the easiest and shortest possible way.

How can i take out keys from node object inside array and place them at the same height as the main array:

What i have:

```
[{ name: 'name 1', id: 1, node: [{ name: 'name2', id: 2 }]}]
```

What i want:

```
[{name: 'name 1', id: 1}, {name: 'name 2', id: 2}]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You should add the code you have used, and told us how the expected output differs from the current output

Comment: I'm stuck trying to flatten everything with the help of a lodash. But I would not like to finally use the lodash library for this

`return _.chain(mainArray)
   .flatten()
   .map('node')
   .flatten()
   .value()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with reduce. You recursively traverse the nodes and concat an array with name and id only. Hope this helps.

```js
const data = [{ name: 'name 1', id: 1, node: [{ name: 'name2', id: 2 }]}];

const flatten = (array = []) =>
    array.reduce((acc, { name, id, node }) =>
        acc.concat(flatten(node)).concat({ name, id })
    , []);

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming your structure always looks like that:

Array of objects containing always 1 object, and that object always have a `node` element (that is another array of objects) you need to do it like this (pseudocode):

```js
mainArray = [{ name: 'name 1', id: 1, node: [{ name: 'name2', id: 2 }]}];
console.log(mainArray);

node = mainArray[0].node[0];
delete mainArray[0].node;
mainArray.push (node);

console.log(mainArray);
```

Since you don't specify any more about your data structure I can't do anything more specific, but you probably can adapt from that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code, that does what you're looking for. There's a couple of console.log statements to guide you through the data that's being processed. I'm sure you'll need to tweak it, but it's a start.

There are 3 forEach loops in this solution, so if you're working on a large array/object, and/or running this frequently - there might be more efficient methods to achieve this goal.

Assuming ECMA6:

```
const arr = [{ name: 'name 1', id: 1, node: [{ name: 'name2', id: 2 }]}];
arr.forEach((item) =>{
    console.log("array item:", item);
    const keys = Object.keys(item);
    console.log("item keys", keys);
    keys.forEach((key) =>{
        if(item[key] instanceof Object){
            if(Array.isArray(item[key])){
                item[key].forEach((internalObject) =>{
                    console.log("intenal object", internalObject);
                    arr.push(internalObject);
                    delete item[key];
                    console.log("New array", arr);
                })
            }
        }
    })
});
```